# Windows 8.1 Video Screensaver shows grey film

Tags: windows-8.1, video, screensaver

I have a touch screen on display. I want the system to have a little video screen saver. I installed Windows Essentials so I would have this functionality. When trying to play the screensaver all I see is a grey filmstrip

- The OS is Windows 8.1
- The file is .wmv format
- The issue happens whether I tell the screensaver to play from the photo gallery or from a specific folder
- The file plays fine in both Windows Media Player and in Photo Gallery

Any suggestions?